# I am trying to get the number of the matching character (I mean how many character are matched) in java

Tags: java, string

So far I have written some code. I have two Strings and I need to compare the string characters and if both Strings are the same, I want to get the number of matches characters.

Below is my code so far. I split the String into a character array and compare the Strings to get the matching character, but I cannot get the number of the matched Strings.

```
public class labExtra {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        double l1,l2,biggerN;
        String name1="Siti";
        String name2="Ali";
        l1=name1.length();
        l2=name2.length();
        if(l1>l2) {
            biggerN=l1;
        }
        else {
            biggerN=l2;
        }
        char [] shojib=name1.toCharArray();
        char [] farhana=name2.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<shojib.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<farhana.length; j++) {
                if(shojib[i]==farhana[j]) {
                    System.out.println(shojib[i]);
                    // ans=new char[shojib[i]];
                    // char [] newary=shojib[i];
                }
            }
            // System.out.println(ans[i]);
        }
        // System.out.println(newary[0]);
        // System.out.print(biggerN);
    }
}
```

How can I get how many characters are matched?

In my code one String is `siti` and the other is `ali`, so there are 3 matching characters but I don't know how to get this number. Please help me to finish the code. I am really in trouble.

Thanks in advance dude.

Comment: Questions like these are better suited at Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Why don't you read up on regex's?

Comment: @AvivCohn I am pretty sure this is StackOverflow.com

Comment: how exactly is the matching number **3** ?

Comment: you can optimize your code by using int instead of double variables for length.

Comment: @Zhuinden, I think they're counting the number of characters in each string, that's the only way I can see them getting 3 for 'i'.

Comment: matching characters count is 1 not 3 .....in siti and ali only i is common ,simply we can tell matching character is "i".........am i right????

Comment: Actually I am looking for how many matching number there have, which total 3 not 1 (Only one character is matching but I need total number which is 3)

Answer (score 0):

Try if this helps:

```
char[] firstString  = word1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
char[] secondString = word2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

int minLength = Math.min(firstString.length, secondString.length);
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
{
        if (firstString[i] == secondString[i])
        {
            counter++;    
        }
}
```

Comment: condition should be  if (firstString[i] == secondString[i]) not !=

Comment: Please see Zhuinden comment for "counter" variable in above answer. You can change it to "count" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need a counter, for example count, starting from 0 that counts matching chars.
In the for loop, until i is less than the shorter string, every time shorter[i]==longer[i] you increase count by 1, outside the for loop you print count!

So it's something like:

```
for(i=0;i<shorter.length();i++){
    if(shorter[i] == longer[i]){
        count+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you really use the indexing variable as the "counter"... this is broken.

Comment: by counter++ only shows how many character are matched, its not ful fil my requirement

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want counts of every matching characters from the strings. You can achieve it by using it Map. When you get a first character matched and count 1, add it to the map. Check for the key every time it matches the character, if it has the value then increase the value by one and add it with the same key. I am posting the same program with some modifications.

```
public class JavaNet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double l1, l2, biggerN;
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        String name1 = "Siti";
        String name2 = "Ali";
        l1 = name1.length();
        l2 = name2.length();

        if (l1 > l2) {
            biggerN = l1;
        } else {
            biggerN = l2;
        }

        char[] shojib = name1.toCharArray();
        char[] farhana = name2.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < shojib.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < farhana.length; j++) {
                if (shojib[i] == farhana[j]) {
                    System.out.println(shojib[i]);
                    int count = map.get(shojib[i] + "") != null ? map.get(shojib[i] + "") : 0;
                    map.put(shojib[i] + "", ++count);
                }
            }
            //  System.out.println(ans[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
        //     System.out.println(newary[0]);
        //  System.out.print(biggerN);
    }
}
```

A use case of this question would have given clearer idea of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a general idea. Though it seems a bit complex.
Initialize a hash map.
Iterate through the first string and create a map of the characters and their occurrences. This should be simple. If a key already exists increment its value else place 1.

Do the same for 2nd string.

Now iterate through any one of the hashmaps. When you encounter a key in say map1 look for the value in the same key in map2(O(1) lookup). Compare the 2 values. When they are same say `x` the value is `x`. When one is greater than the other say `a` and `b` the value is `a-b`. Now add all of this and you have the number of similar characters

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Compare{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String word1 = "Siti";
        String word2 = "Ali";

        Map<Character,Integer> m = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

        char[] charWord1  = word1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] charWord2 = word2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

        for(int i=0;i<charWord1.length;i++)
        {
            Integer freq = m.get(charWord1[i]);
            m.put(charWord1[i], (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<charWord2.length;i++)
        {
            Integer freq = m.get(charWord2[i]);
            m.put(charWord2[i], (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Use a map, go through each word separately, return instance count.

This code produces: `{t=1, s=1, a=1, l=1, i=3}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below example. The code is explained with the comments.

```
public class Compare{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name1 = "Siti";
        String name2 = "Ali";
        String matchedChars = "";

        String comBinedString = name1 + name2;

        for (int i = 0; i < comBinedString.length(); i++) {

            //Only proceed if the character has not occured previously
            if(!matchedChars.contains(comBinedString.charAt(i) + "")){
                countOccurencesAndPrint(comBinedString, i); 
            } else {
                //Skip the loop and no need to add in the matchedChars
                continue;
            }

            //Add the current character matched to matchedChars
            matchedChars += comBinedString.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    private static void countOccurencesAndPrint(String stringToBeCompared, int charIndex) {
        int counter = 0;
        for( int i=0; i<stringToBeCompared.length(); i++ ) {
            if( stringToBeCompared.charAt(i) == stringToBeCompared.charAt(charIndex) ) {
                counter++;
            } 
        }

        System.out.println("Character " + stringToBeCompared.charAt(charIndex)+ " found " + counter + " times");

    }
}
```

This will give you the output:

```
Character S found 1 times
Character i found 3 times
Character t found 1 times
Character A found 1 times
Character l found 1 times
```